# VisualAssistX is messing up my C++ VS2008 colour scheme

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, color-scheme, visual-assist

I have VisualAssistX installed on my VS2008 IDE, and I have set all the colouring options I could find (VS Fonts & colours as well as VisualAssistX options colours) to defaults

However, when I turn on VAX, I go from my regular scheme

[image]

to THIS

[image]

I have also tried resetting all VS2008 settings through the import/export menu with no effect

What am I missing? Where are these colours coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Assist has its own colors for items it detects. It calls this Enhanced Syntax Coloring. You can change this in the interface for Visual Assist.

Click on the icon that looks like a Tomato with a gear in front of it. Then Advanced. Then Fonts and Colors. Then uncheck "Enable Enhanced Syntax Coloring"

Comment: I did uncheck enhanced syntax coloring, and restarted VS, but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: For me after I turn off the "Enhanced Syntax Coloring" checkbox and click apply then close the dialog box the extra coloring goes away. If this is not happening for you it may be a bug in the current version. I am not using that since my maintenance period is over.